# update .copyFrom with the last non-empty cell in a worksheet using office script

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I have a problem updating the copied version of the main sheet.

I created a button in the sheet to obtain a copy of the main sheet but with the filtered values on column 7 and 5.

The problem is that we need sometimes to add new items to the list, which makes the range to grow.
I can solve the issue by updating the function manually in this line of code

```
// Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A1:E5000"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.formats, false, false);
  // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom from range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A1:E5000"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
```

and changing to a non-empty range, e.g., if I add one item I will need to change to 5001.
If I try to add a random long number (for example 6000) so I can always be on the use table range, then the function copies all values in the mainsheet including those that are not in the filtered function.

I looked up the function .Range.getRangeEdge and Range.getExtendedRange but I cannot figureout how to add it in the copyFrom formulae. Some ideas.

##### This code is to generate a list of items that are filtered according the filtered columns

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let mainSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  // Check if the "Data" worksheet already exists.
  if (workbook.getWorksheet("TestSheet")) {
    console.log("The Data worksheet is already in the workbook. It will be deleted to add as new.");
    let transferSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("TestSheet");
    transferSheet.delete();
    workbook.addWorksheet("TestSheet");
  } else {
    // Add a new worksheet.
    let transferSheet = workbook.addWorksheet("TestSheet");
  }

  let transferSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("TestSheet");
  // Toggle auto filter on selectedSheet
  mainSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(mainSheet.getRange("H1"));
  // Apply values filter on selectedSheet
  mainSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(mainSheet.getAutoFilter().getRange(), 7, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["x"] });
  //mainSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(mainSheet.getAutoFilter().getRange(), 7, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: ["x"] });
  // Apply values filter on selectedSheet
  mainSheet.getAutoFilter().apply(mainSheet.getAutoFilter().getRange(), 5, { filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, values: [""] });


  // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A1:E5000"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.formats, false, false);
  // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A1:E5000"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
  // Auto fit the columns of range range E:E on TestSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("E:E").getFormat().autofitColumns();
  // Auto fit the columns of range range E:E on TestSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("D:D").getFormat().autofitColumns();
  // Auto fit the columns of range range C:C on TestSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("C:C").getFormat().autofitColumns();
  // Auto fit the columns of range range B:B on TestSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("B:B").getFormat().autofitColumns();
  // Auto fit the columns of range range A:A on TestSheet
  transferSheet.getRange("A:A").getFormat().autofitColumns();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using column references? You would update your copy and paste lines from this:

```js
    // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
      transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A1:E5000"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.formats, false, false);
      // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom from range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
      transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A1:E5000"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
```

to this:

```js
    // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
      transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A:E"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.formats, false, false);
      // Paste to range A1 on TestSheetfrom from range A1:E3095 on selectedSheet
      transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange("A:E"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
```

You could even use the intersect operator (the space character) with the getRange() and getUsedRange() methods to give you the number of rows dynamically. If you wanted to go that route you would use something like this:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
        let usedRangeAddy: string = sh.getUsedRange().getAddress()
        let rang: ExcelScript.Range = sh.getRange(`A:E ${usedRangeAddy}`)
    }
```

Or if you wanted to access the Used Range's row property directly, you could write code like this:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
        let usedRangeRows: number = sh.getUsedRange().getRowCount()
        let rang: ExcelScript.Range = sh.getRange(`A1:E${usedRangeRows}`)
    }
```

Comment: I solved so far using the proposed dynamic solution. I used the operator in usedRangeAddy directly at the  lines 
`transferSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(mainSheet.getRange(``A1:E${usedRangeAddy.substr(-4, 4)}``), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.formats, false, false);` .  by formating the string created by the instruction.

Unfortunately, the first solution does not work (or does similar as my original try). I don't get it why. Try this: Make a two rows, with one containing an x in field 7 (H) and the other empty. You will see that it copies all the data including the empty field.

Comment: If you want to get the rows from the usedRangeAddy variables, you don't need to extract the rows that way. You can just access the row properties directly. I will update my answer so you can see what that would look like.